# preposition "travel in" or "travel by"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Which is the grammatically correct statement :

"We are travelling in a car"

Or

"We are travelling by a car"

Comment: The construction "*travel in a car*" focuses on your current location (physically located inside a car); "*travel by car*" (not *by **a** car*) focuses on the method of travel. By contrast, "*travel by **a** car*" indicates you *passed by a car* on your trip.

Comment: See this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/17946/18696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another smaller nuance is that in America (US) we spell it "traveling". Don't know if the question was about British usage or American.

Answer (score 0):

If you say travel by something, it means you are travelling by the means of transportation. For example, "I travelled by car" means that I am travelling using a car for transportation.

If you say travel in something, it means you are literally travelling while inside a specific vehicle. For example, "I travelled in a car" means that you are travelling literally inside a car.

Comment: Unless you ride on the roof, it's hard to travel by car without being in a car. The real distinction is the nuance Dan Bron mentioned in his comment.